# Excel Named Range for a Chart Syntax?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

Good Afternoon all,

I'm currently trying to dynamise the visible left and right 'sides' (start and end) of a chart by date for a report.

I've put together two defined `Names` by two Start and End Date cells, which is fantastic. These are simply called `ReportStartDate` and `ReportEndDate` and will return the start and end cell references for a table of data for my report.

Now I have two variables holding cell references, for example, `$A$1` and `$B$20` - so in theory, I should only need to place a colon between these to form a valid Series Value in the `Select Data` portion of my Excel Chart.

However, no luck as it returns `#VALUE!`. Any ideas on how to implement this properly? Many thanks.

Ps. The application of `&` does not help as it simply returns a typical invalid function syntax pop up.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to look back at your named ranges and create a named range that covers all cells between ReportStartDate and ReportEndDate

For example -
if `ReportStartDate` is in A1 and `ReportEndDate` is in a cell below that you could create a third named range which I'll call `FullRange`:
`=StartCell:INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$A,MATCH(EndCell,Sheet1!$A:$A,0))`

Now, clicking on your chart series you'll get a formula appear in the formula bar that will look similar to:
`=SERIES(,Sheet1!$C$1:$C$9,Sheet1!$A$1:$A$9,1)`

You can replace those series with named ranges - remembering to use the workbook name as well:
`=SERIES(,Sheet1!$C$1:$C$9,Book1.xlsx!FullRange,1)`

Jon Peltier explains it much better here: http://peltiertech.com/chart-range-endpoints/